# Retaining the state of an object in JavaScript & convert it into text which can be passed as parameter(as object) to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a UI where user makes selection & click on process button. On click on button, system calls a method written in JavaScript and it returns a object which looks like this.

```
{
     "users": [{
         "id": 1,
         "name": "Ed",
         "orders": [{
             "id": 10,
             "total": 10.76,
             "status": "invoiced"
        },{
             "id": 11,
             "total": 13.45,
             "status": "shipped"
        }]
     }]
 }
```

**What I want:**

I want to pass this JavaScript object to a method which should generate a **text** producing output like this:

```
{
         "users": [{
             "id": 1,
             "name": "Ed",
             "orders": [{
                 "id": 10,
                 "total": 10.76,
                 "status": "invoiced"
            },{
                 "id": 11,
                 "total": 13.45,
                 "status": "shipped"
            }]
         }]
     }
```

I should be able to pass a real JavaScript object to this method and by going over the object it should produce a text showcasing the structure of this object.

**In .net world we can do this by using reflection** and then return the string. We also have option of serializing the object into XML or JSON or any other format.

Is it possible with JavaScript.

Why I want to do this.

I have written 50 test cases which expects this object as input. I can take output of the method and pass it to any testcase.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method. It does exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just googled and saw this method :). I will mark this as answer after system allows me :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should add your stringified object to some `<pre>` and `<code>` tags to get the best output.

```
<div><pre><code class="text"></code></pre></div>
```

And then use the [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) `spaces` parameter:

```
$('.text').html(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

You can also use tabs if you want.

```
$('.text').html(JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CP99A/6/)

Comment: Thank you for reply. voting it up for fiddle :)